# Google maps navigation when I click on marker icon

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

I have to navigate the page from one view controller to another view controller when user clicks on marker icon using Google maps.

Answer (score 0):

we have to place a delegate in

```
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:yourFloat longitude:yourFloat1 zoom:15];

mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:self.view.frame camera:camera];

mapView.delegate = self;

self.view = mapView;
```

While giving frame to map view at that time only we have to call delegate method.

Answer (score -1):

Set the `mapView.delegate = self`, then use -

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {
     <#navigation code here#>
}
```

For Objective-C method refer to this -  [Protocol Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/protocol_g_m_s_map_view_delegate-p.html#ae291e1bff99f9d06428ced09daf5802d)

Comment: hai Akash, I tried but it is not working in objective-c

Comment: check the updated answer and make sure you have set the mapView delegate

Answer (score -1):

You can use this function, remember to **return false** otherwise it doesn't work .

```
   func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {

     return false
   }
```